# R Shiny: Multiple dynamically created plots - positioning does not work

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinydashboard

Dear R Shiny programmers,
I want to include two dynamically created plots into my Dashboard, each of them on a separate `menuItem`. I am using `uiOutput("plot_1")` to define the first plot on one `menuItem` and then I am defining another one with `uiOutput("plot_2")` on a DIFFERENT `menuItem`. Then, within server I am using `output$plot_1 <- renderUI({ some code })` to render the first dynamic plot and `output$plot_2 <- renderUI({ some code })` to render the second dynamic plot. However, only the first one of the plots (plot_1) shows up and with the plot title of the second plot!! The second plot (plot_2) which was supposed to show on the `menuItem` I defined it within the `ui` does not show at all. 
Could you help me please?

Below I created the code example which can easily reproduce my problem:

```
max_plots <- 5

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Show dynamic plots"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Slider 1", tabName = "tab_1", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Slider 2", tabName = "tab_2", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("First Plot", tabName = "tab_3", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Second Plot", tabName = "tab_4", icon = icon("line-chart"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_1",

              fluidRow(
                box(title = "", status = "primary", width = 12,
                    sliderInput("n_1", "Number of plots 1", value=1, min=1, max=5)
                )
              )

      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_2",

              fluidRow(
                box(title = "", status = "primary", width = 12,
                    sliderInput("n_2", "Number of plots 2", value=1, min=1, max=5)
                )
              )

      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_3",

              fluidRow(
                box(title = "", status = "primary", width = 12,
                    uiOutput("plot_1")
                )
              )

      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab_4",

              fluidRow(
                box(title = "", status = "primary", width = 12,
                    uiOutput("plot_2")
                )
              )

      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {

## For dynamic plot 1
  output$plot_1 <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list_1 <- lapply(1:input$n_1, function(i) {
      plotname_1 <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname_1, height = 280, width = 250)
    })

    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list_1)

  })

  for (i in 1:max_plots) {
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname_1 <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

      output[[plotname_1]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
             xlim = c(1, max_plots),
             ylim = c(1, max_plots),
             main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n_1 is ", input$n_1, sep = "")
        )
      })
    })
  }


  ## For dynamic plot 2
  output$plot_2 <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list_2 <- lapply(1:input$n_2, function(i) {
      plotname_2 <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname_2, height = 280, width = 250)
    })

    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list_2)

  })

  for (i in 1:max_plots) {
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname_2 <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

      output[[plotname_2]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
             xlim = c(1, max_plots),
             ylim = c(1, max_plots),
             main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n_2 is ", input$n_2, sep = "")
        )
      })
    })
  }


}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can you please somebody help me that the first plot gets created on one `menuItem` and the second plot gets created on a different `menuItem`? Also, please note that in my original code the `renderPlot({})` function is not similar for the two plots - the dynamic plots are different.

Comment: You have duplicated id's: `paste("plot", i, sep="")` for both plots. You must use uniques id's.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue! Great!